# Code error in querying Firebase collection - Typescript

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Forewarning, I'm an UX designer just trying to create an API on my own, so this is definitely beyond my knowledge of coding for the most part.

I'm trying to create a serverless REST API using NodeJS and Google Cloud Functions. However, in my code for querying a Firestore Collection, I get the following error from Typescript.

Variable 'popups' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.

Below is my code.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

const app = express();
const main = express();

main.use("/api/v1", app);
main.use(bodyParser.json());

export const webApi = functions.https.onRequest(main);

app.get("/startup", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Starting API Service.");
});

app.post("/popups", async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const { popName, popTwitter, popLocation } = request.body;
    const data = {
      popName,
      popTwitter,
      popLocation
    };
   const popupRef = await db.collection("popups").add(data);
    const popup = await popupRef.get();

    response.json({
      id: popupRef.id,
      data: popup.data()
    });
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
app.get("/popups/:id", async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const popupId = request.params.id;

    if (!popupId) throw new Error("PopUp ID is required");

    const popup = await db
      .collection("popups")
      .doc(popupId)
      .get();

    if (!popup.exists) {
      throw new Error("PopUp does not exist.");
    }

    response.json({
      id: popup.id,
      data: popup.data()
    });
  } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
app.get("/popups", async (request, response) => {
  try {
    const popupQuerySnapshot = await db.collection("popups").get();
    const popups = [];
    popupQuerySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      popups.push({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data()
       });
    });

    response.json(popups);
   } catch (error) {
    response.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Typescript Config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is that an error or just a warning?  Is that coming from the TypeScript compiler, or tslint?  I don't get that with the bit of code that deals with `popups`.  Care to share your full TypeScript configuration?

Comment: looks like you need either specify the type explicitly or relax an option in your tsconfig

Comment: I added the Typescript Config above

Comment: Could you go back and answer all the questions that I asked in the first comment?

Comment: The error seems to be coming from tslint. I went back and removed it from the configuration and was able to get it to compile and deploy without an issue.

Comment: Maybe you could answer your own question with the details that resolved this issue?